# SQLite Cursor limit - 1MB

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-cursor

I've found out that the cursor could hold only maximum 1MB.
Does it mean that if I have 3 rows that each of those rows are 400KB in size. (Which means that the 3 of them together are 1.2MB in size).

I query those 3 rows with one cursor, will it work, or not? Does the cursor limit the size per row or per query?

If it does per query, what is the best way to extract the data out of my DB? Will I have to create seperate queries for each row because of that 1MB limit..?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

SQLite computes result records on demand and thus has forward-only cursors.
To allow moving backwards through cursors, the Android API reads all results into memory when you open a cursor.

The 1 MB *query* limit is there to prevent nonsensical queries from bogging down the device.

[Large blobs should not be stored in the database but in the file system](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First, I'd like to say that I MUST store the BLOBs in the DB(It is encrypted in there using SQLCipher). Second, As I understand from you, it is 1MB per row? If so, why do I get that error?

Comment: Each row of my database is max 400KB.. I shouldn't get that error right?

Comment: *All* records are read first; the limit applies to the entire result set.

Comment: Aha, I see. Have any idea on how I should get my data off the DB then?

Comment: So that limitation won't occur.

Comment: If the blobs are guaranteed to be smaller than 1 MB, use one query per record. Otherwise, use files and [encrypt](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) them yourself.